# Surjective linear transformation onto a potentially infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

This is from Chapter $2.4$ question $25$ from Friedberg's Linear algebra text:

Let $V$ be a nonzero vector space over the field $F$, and suppose that $S$ is a basis for $V$. Let $C(S, F)$ denote the vector space of all funtions $f \in F(S, F)$ such that $f(s) = 0$ for all but a finite number of vectors in $S$. Let $\Psi: C(S, F) \to V$ be the function defined by

$$\Psi(f) = \sum\limits_{s \in S, f(s) \neq 0} f(s) s$$

Prove that $\Psi$ is an isomorphism.

I've already done the linearity and one-to-one portions of the proof, but I don't know how to tackle the surjective argument for the case where $V$ is not finite dimensional. I don't see how we could define a function that maps to an infinitely large linear combination of vectors in $S$, as in $s_1 + s_2 \ldots$ where all coefficients are non-zero. There obviously cannot be any such function in $F(S, F)$ because of the $f(s) = 0$ requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of a basis any vector $v \in V$ can be written as a **finite linear combination** $v= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_is_i$ with $s_i \in S$ for all $i$. Let $f(s_i)=a_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $f(s)=0$ when $s \notin \{s_1,s_2,..,s_n\}$. Then $\Psi (f) =v$.